# osticket how to get ticket id by the form entry value?

Tags: mysql, osticket

In osticket we have a number of custom form fields setup and I need help querying them. The data that I want to query is stored in `form_entry.value`.

```
SELECT * FROM `form_entry_values` fev, `form_entry` fe WHERE fev.value = '{$ibn}' AND fe.id = fev.entry_id
```

This is returning the correct data but how can I find the ticket ID if i know the form_id? I can't seem to find any joining tables.

This is the full db: https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.8/blob/b1c845bf0591b1f5da593a55e462b07e5a4ee5de/setup/inc/streams/core/install-mysql.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `form`;
CREATE TABLE `form` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'G',
    `deletable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `instructions` varchar(512),
    `notes` text,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `form_field`;
CREATE TABLE `form_field` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `form_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
    `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `private` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit_mask` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `configuration` text,
    `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `hint` varchar(512),
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `form_entry`;
CREATE TABLE `form_entry` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `form_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `object_id` int(11) unsigned,
    `object_type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'T',
    `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `entry_lookup` (`object_type`, `object_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `form_entry_values`;
CREATE TABLE `form_entry_values` (
    -- references form_entry.id
    `entry_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `value` text,
    `value_id` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`, `field_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `list`;
CREATE TABLE `list` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `name_plural` varchar(255),
    `sort_mode` enum('Alpha', '-Alpha', 'SortCol') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Alpha',
    `masks` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `type` VARCHAR( 16 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `notes` text,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `type` (`type`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `list_items`;
CREATE TABLE `list_items` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `list_id` int(11),
    `status` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -- extra value such as abbreviation
    `extra` varchar(255),
    `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `properties` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `list_item_lookup` (`list_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `number` varchar(20),
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `user_email_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `dept_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `sla_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `topic_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `staff_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `email_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `flags` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `source` enum('Web','Email','Phone','API','Other') NOT NULL default 'Other',
  `isoverdue` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `isanswered` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `duedate` datetime default NULL,
  `reopened` datetime default NULL,
  `closed` datetime default NULL,
  `lastmessage` datetime default NULL,
  `lastresponse` datetime default NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ticket_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `dept_id` (`dept_id`),
  KEY `staff_id` (`staff_id`),
  KEY `team_id` (`team_id`),
  KEY `status_id` (`status_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `closed` (`closed`),
  KEY `duedate` (`duedate`),
  KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`),
  KEY `sla_id` (`sla_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_attachment`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_attachment` (
  `attach_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ref_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `inline` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default  '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`attach_id`),
  KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
  KEY `ref_id` (`ref_id`),
  KEY `file_id` (`file_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_lock`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_lock` (
  `lock_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `staff_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `expire` datetime default NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`lock_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
  KEY `staff_id` (`staff_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_email_info`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_email_info` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `thread_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email_mid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `headers` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email_mid` (`email_mid`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_event`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_event` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `staff_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dept_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` enum('created','closed','reopened','assigned','transferred','overdue') NOT NULL,
  `staff` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'SYSTEM',
  `annulled` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `ticket_state` (`ticket_id`, `state`, `timestamp`),
  KEY `ticket_stats` (`timestamp`, `state`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_status`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mode` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `properties` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `state` (`state`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_priority`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_priority` (
  `priority_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `priority` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `priority_desc` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `priority_color` varchar(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `priority_urgency` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ispublic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`priority_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `priority` (`priority`),
  KEY `priority_urgency` (`priority_urgency`),
  KEY `ispublic` (`ispublic`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ticket_thread`;
CREATE TABLE `ticket_thread` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `staff_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned not null default 0,
  `thread_type` enum('M','R','N') NOT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `source` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `title` varchar(255),
  `body` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `format` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'html',
  `ip_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
  KEY `staff_id` (`staff_id`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ticket_collaborator` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ticket_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  -- M => (message) clients, N => (note) 3rd-Party, R => (reply) external authority
  `role` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `collab` (`ticket_id`,`user_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the values table, there is a field `object_id` this is the ticket ID.

```
SELECT t.* FROM form_entry_values fev 
  LEFT JOIN form_entry fe ON(fev.entry_id = fe.id) 
  LEFT JOIN ticket t ON(fe.object_id = t.ticket_id) 
WHERE fev.value = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Osticket 1.15 version, the `object_id` in the form_entry has a relation to the user_id.

```
SELECT t.* FROM form_entry_values fev 
  LEFT JOIN form_entry fe ON fev.entry_id = fe.id 
  LEFT JOIN ticket t ON fe.object_id = t.user_id
```